# Calculating significance between ratios made of two means

Tags: statistical-significance, ratio

I am trying to find a test to analyze the significance between ratios of two means.

I am doing a study that investigates the expression of a certain protein in the brain following an experiment. I have 2 populations - experimental (n=3) and control group (n=3), and in these groups I have an internal control (n=30 each), which is basically the area of the brain that would not be affected by the experiment, and the area that will be affected by the experiment (n=30 each). Which test should I use in order to compare the average ratio of the area that will be affected by the experiment and the internal control between the experimental and control group?